# How to determine the function of a graph that shows up straight on a lin-log plot

Tags: python, function, matplotlib, logarithm

this is more of a math question, but hopefully you will be able to help or direct me to a source where I can find the answer.

I want to find out the function a graph that would show up as a straight line if plotted on the following lin-log scale. Simply connecting the start and end point won't do; I need to be able to determine any y-value corresponding to a given x-value.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpoZj.png)

I managed to do this for a different case where the function started at 0 (excluding actual 0), but I can't figure out how to apply that logic to the first problem:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpoZj.png)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

X = [x for x in range(1,100)]

base = 100**(1/100)
Y = [math.log(x,base) for x in X]

plt.semilogx(X,Y)
plt.xlim(1,100000)
plt.ylim(0,100)
plt.show()
```

Would really appreciate if someone could help me out!

Comment: The function you showed is y = x

Comment: @Mitchel0022, please note that the x-scale is logarithmic, therefore the graph is not in fact linear.